# Showing only Text and Image of any URL in webview

Tags: android, webview

I am using webview.
I have a URL http://www.bbc.com/sport/cricket/38957606
I only want to show the text and images of this webpage.
I do not want to show the whole webpage.
I am passing the url via Intent.

## WebView

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {
private WebView webView;
private String uri;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    String url = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
    Toast.makeText(this, "...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: and... what's the question? why are you expecting it to show only text and images?

Comment: in order to load webpage data fast just text and image no other formatting

Comment: do you mean the entire web page text and images? or just a title/header image?

Comment: entire webpage text and images (only header image will also work)

Comment: this link might help you: http://androidforums.com/threads/webview-to-load-only-text-from-a-page.98464/

Comment: @DanielPuiu Thanks.. m looking into your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you exactly want.

you can parse the Title, Description, and Images from the Url. So you can use this library to crawl HTML and parse

https://github.com/LeonardoCardoso/Android-Link-Preview

Comment: as the webpage takes time to load so I want to only show the relevant data which is only text on this webpage and a header picture. No formatting

Comment: its not helping

Comment: Then there is now way. how can you get the website without crawling? Other options is make web service which can only return data whatever you need

Comment: Use JSoup to crawl the html tag and parse whatever you needed. That library use that concept

Comment: I want to show only the text just like the only text option Safari has the when we open a webpage

Answer (score 1):

Mostly the main content of news site is under a "div" and probably used class like "content", main-content". 
Looks like this :
Look picture..
(Sorry for that I'm using mobile phone to write this :( )

Find that div. 
Add this library into build graddle file:
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.3'

And use:
Elements info = doc.select("div.yourClassName");

İf div doesn't includes class attribute (class="..someClass... " ), it probably use Id. Find  id="..someId.." and use this:
Elements info = doc.select("div#yourIDName");

Know you get main content of website. For further information plesase search online "Jsoup" library. Have a nice day [image]

Comment: sorry I couldn't get that